# "water pool" vs "swimming pool"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Is it correct to use **water pool** instead of **swimming pool**? In some hotel descriptions I have found **water pool**, but it looks like it was a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Hotels **can** typically invent creative names for their facilities -- no grammatical/ literary oversight needed.

A water pool is just that, a pool of water. A swimming pool is a pool of water specially designated for the purpose of swimming.

It is not common to refer to a swimming pool as a water pool at all.

One plausibility, however, is:
A suitable pool of water where swimming is allowed, such as part of a lake (esp. in rural areas). It is quite common for people to swim in natural pools of water regularly used for the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Swimming pool is a container filled with water for the purpose of swimming or other water based recreations. Water pool also the means the same but its scarcely used. Its not a mistake they just wanted to put it in a different way probably.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that they use water pool to pre-warn guests that it is not a pool for althletic training like swimming laps.

Just as you would say "wading pool" if it was 1' deep, not "swimming pool."